# Programmatically adding thousands of Android contacts in bulk

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

Using the ContentResolver.applyBatch and ContentResolver.bulkInsert methods to add thousands of contacts in one go is very slow. Does Android provide a different way to bulk add contacts which would be substantially quicker?

I've so far tried the following approaches:

**Using applyBatch (~75 seconds per thousand contacts)**

For each contact:

- Create a new ContentValues object to represent a raw contact
- Build a new ContentProviderOperation to insert this into the RawContacts table
- Add this operation to a list and store its index
- Create ContentValues objects for other contact fields like names and phone numbers
- Build a new ContentProviderOperation to insert each of these into the Data table with a backreference to the raw contact insert operation
- Add these operations to the list

Finally, use ContentResolver.applyBatch to apply all operations.

**Using bulkInsert (~40 seconds per thousand contacts)**

For each contact:

- Create a new ContentValues object to represent a raw contact
- Build a new ContentProviderOperation to insert this into the RawContacts table
- Add this operation to a list

Then, use ContentResolver.applyBatch to apply all operations. This returns an array of ContentProviderResults.

Now, for each contact:

- Parse the raw contact ID from the corresponding ContentProviderResult.
- Construct an array of ContentValues objects for all the data fields for the contact, each with a field for the raw contact ID
- Use ContentResolver.bulkInsert to insert these into the Data table

**Questions**

- In the second approach I first do applyBatch for the RawContacts table entries then bulkInsert for the Data table entried. This is because I can't figure out a way to provide the raw contact IDs for the Data entries otherwise. Is there something similar to backreferences for bulkInsert that would allow me to add the RawContacts and Data entries at the same time?
- applyBatch and bulkInsert can only perform so many inserts in one batch before they complain that the transaction is too large. Consequently they have to be applied every 500 contacts or so. Is there a way to change this limit?
- Is there some completely different, quicker way to add thousands of contacts at once?

Answer (score 0):

The **first method** you've showed is the right way to go, other then being faster then the **second method**, it's safer as well.

As you're inserting both to `RawContacts` and `Data` in the same batch operation, if something goes wrong along the way, the DB will rollback the previous changes on that batch so you're not left with any *zombie* info in either table.

To speed things up, try dividing the work between different threads.

If you have 1000 contacts, create one thread that will process the top 500, and another one to process the bottom 500, and have them run simultaneously.
You can apply that to more threads if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. I am a bit confused though since my own testing for implementations #1 and #2 showed that #2 was almost twice as fast. However, I can appreciate the robustness argument.

Comment: For some reason, when I do `applyBatch` on different threads, the batches have to be smaller or I get a `TransactionTooLargeException`. When I've reduced the batch size to something acceptable, it ends up being no quicker than doing everything synchronously. Maybe this is being imposed by `ContentResolver`?